# How to construct an ephemeral File on NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, openai-api

### I would like to get a webm file from firebase bucket and transcribe it using openai whisper.

So far I'm generating a public URL for the file in the bucket, shooting a request with axios and creating a blob.

```js
export const getFile = async(publicUrl: string) => {
    const response = await axios.get(publicUrl, { responseType: 'blob' })
    return new Blob([response.data], { type: 'video/webm' })
}
```

In the official openai nodejs package the function I want to invoke is:

```js
createTranscription(file: File, model: string, prompt?: string, responseFormat?: string, temperature?: number, language?: string, options?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<import("axios").AxiosResponse<CreateTranscriptionResponse, any>>;
```

Now as per openai documentation:

> file Required. The audio file to transcribe, in one of these formats: mp3, mp4, mpeg, mpga, m4a, wav, or webm.

I'm having trouble converting this `Blob` into a `File` OR getting the `File` object from the firebase storage bucket.

### What I've tried

#### Constructing the file

```js
    const file = new File([blob], "test.webm", {
      type: "video/webm",
    });
```

I'll get a: `ReferenceError: File is not defined`, to my understanding I cannot use the File javascript object.

#### Adding needed properties onto the blob

A `Blob` and a `File` is close to being the same, so I tried adding the missing properties:

```js
const resp = await openai.createTranscription(
      {...blob, lastModified: 0, webkitRelativePath: "", name: "test.webm"},
      "whisper-1"
    );
```

Which typescript doesn't like:

```
Argument of type '{ lastModified: number; webkitRelativePath: string; name: string; size: number; type: string; arrayBuffer(): Promise<ArrayBuffer>; slice(start?: number | undefined, end?: number | undefined, contentType?: string | undefined): Blob; stream(): ReadableStream<...>; text(): Promise<...>; prototype: Blob; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'File'.
  Type '{ lastModified: number; webkitRelativePath: string; name: string; size: number; type: string; arrayBuffer(): Promise<ArrayBuffer>; slice(start?: number | undefined, end?: number | undefined, contentType?: string | undefined): Blob; stream(): ReadableStream<...>; text(): Promise<...>; prototype: Blob; }' provides no match for the signature 'new (blobParts?: BlobPart[] | undefined, options?: BlobPropertyBag | undefined): Blob'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, input was a PDF file uploaded using HTML input type file and I wanted to extract the text from PDF and pass it to the openAI models.

The PDF text extractor required a Buffer object.
Tried multiple hacks/fix couldn't convert/parse the incoming file in node.js

Lastly, I tried `Multer` as a middleware and it worked.

I was using nextjs so this was my code.

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import multer from 'multer';

interface MulterRequest extends NextApiRequest {
    file: multerFile;
    files: Array<multerFile>;
}

const apiRoute = nextConnect({
    onError(error, req: MulterRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
        res.status(501).json({
            error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}`,
        });
    },
    onNoMatch(req, res) {
        res.status(405).json({ error: `Method "${req.method}" Not Allowed` });
    },
});

apiRoute.use(multer().any());

apiRoute.post(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // console.log(req.body, req.files); // Your form data here
        // Any logic with your data here
        const configuration = new Configuration({
            apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
        });
        const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
        // Problem was this part  arg1 type was Buffer
        const data = await PdfParse(req.files[0].buffer);

        const response = await openai....stuff

        console.log(response.data)
        res.status(200).json({ data: response.data.choices })
        // fs.writeFile('./parse.txt', data.text, () => {});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ data: 'Error', error });
    }
});
```

Tl;dr using `multer` as a middleware might fix your problem